# cURL and SFTP Error

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, curl, ftp

I am trying to get SFTP to work with cURL using [these instructions](http://andrewberls.com/blog/post/adding-sftp-support-to-curl), and some help I found from [this post on askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995815/curl-not-accepting-sftp) but I still have an issue. I have followed the instructions that Terrance used and it worked for him but when I try to run the `make` or `make install` commands I get this error: `vtls/openssl.c:2389:20: error`dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘EVP_PKEY {aka struct evp_pkey_st}’ switch(pubkey->type) {`

The whole error log for the `make install` command is as follows:

```
    root@MultiCrew:~/curl-7.47.0# make install
    Making install in lib
    make[1]: Entering directory '/root/curl-7.47.0/lib'
    CC       vtls/libcurl_nss_la-openssl.lo
    vtls/openssl.c: In function ‘Curl_ossl_cleanup’:
    vtls/openssl.c:758:3: warning: ‘ERR_remove_thread_state’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    ERR_remove_thread_state(NULL);
    ^
    In file included from /usr/include/openssl/ui.h:13:0,
     from /usr/include/openssl/engine.h:29,
     from ../lib/urldata.h:88,
     from vtls/openssl.c:41:
    /usr/include/openssl/err.h:247:1: note: declared here
    DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(void ERR_remove_thread_state(void *))
    ^
    vtls/openssl.c: In function ‘verifyhost’:
    vtls/openssl.c:1095:9: warning: ‘ASN1_STRING_data’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    const char *altptr = (char *)ASN1_STRING_data(check->d.ia5);
    ^
    In file included from /usr/include/openssl/bn.h:31:0,
     from /usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:24,
     from /usr/include/openssl/objects.h:916,
     from /usr/include/openssl/evp.h:27,
     from /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:23,
     from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:50,
     from ../lib/urldata.h:86,
     from vtls/openssl.c:41:
    /usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:553:1: note: declared here
    DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(unsigned char *ASN1_STRING_data(ASN1_STRING *x))
    ^
    vtls/openssl.c:1178:15: warning: ‘ASN1_STRING_data’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    memcpy(peer_CN, ASN1_STRING_data(tmp), j);
    ^
    In file included from /usr/include/openssl/bn.h:31:0,
     from /usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:24,
     from /usr/include/openssl/objects.h:916,
     from /usr/include/openssl/evp.h:27,
     from /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:23,
     from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:50,
     from ../lib/urldata.h:86,
     from vtls/openssl.c:41:
    /usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:553:1: note: declared here
    DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(unsigned char *ASN1_STRING_data(ASN1_STRING *x))
    ^
    vtls/openssl.c: In function ‘get_cert_chain’:
    vtls/openssl.c:2353:29: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘X509_get0_signature’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    X509_get0_signature(&psig, &palg, x);
                 ^
    In file included from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:50:0,
     from ../lib/urldata.h:86,
     from vtls/openssl.c:41:
    /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:552:6: note: expected ‘const ASN1_BIT_STRING ** {aka const struct asn1_string_st **}’ but argument is of type ‘ASN1_BIT_STRING ** {aka struct asn1_string_st **}’
    void X509_get0_signature(const ASN1_BIT_STRING **psig,
    ^
    vtls/openssl.c:2353:36: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘X509_get0_signature’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    X509_get0_signature(&psig, &palg, x);
                        ^
    In file included from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:50:0,
     from ../lib/urldata.h:86,
     from vtls/openssl.c:41:
    /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:552:6: note: expected ‘const X509_ALGOR ** {aka const struct X509_algor_st **}’ but argument is of type ‘X509_ALGOR ** {aka struct X509_algor_st **}’
    void X509_get0_signature(const ASN1_BIT_STRING **psig,
    ^
    vtls/openssl.c:2360:27: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘X509V3_ext’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
    X509V3_ext(data, i, X509_get0_extensions(x));
               ^
    vtls/openssl.c:2246:12: note: expected ‘struct stack_st_X509_EXTENSION *’ but argument is of type ‘const struct stack_st_X509_EXTENSION *’
    static int X509V3_ext(struct SessionHandle *data,
    ^
    vtls/openssl.c:2389:20: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘EVP_PKEY {aka struct evp_pkey_st}’
    switch(pubkey->type) {
        ^
    Makefile:1877: recipe for target 'vtls/libcurl_nss_la-openssl.lo' failed
    make[1]: *** [vtls/libcurl_nss_la-openssl.lo] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/curl-7.47.0/lib'
    Makefile:881: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
    make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

`ldd openssl` output

```
ldd openssl
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7792000)
    libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 (0xb7712000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0xb74b9000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb749c000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb72e6000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb72e1000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7793000)
```

Comment: May be you configured curl with inappropriate openssl version. What was your "configure" command line?

Comment: ./configure --disable-shared

Comment: @Oleg, anything wrong with that?

Comment: Maybe openssl libs are different on build and execution. Try to search all of your machine for libssl.so.*

Comment: What command would i run to see that?

Comment: 1) suggest taking the latest curl 7.57
2) for openssl version checking in the directory where you build curl run "ldd openssl" and copy the string which contains libssl.so.* here

Comment: When I run `ldd openssl` it says the directory openssl does not exist

Comment: That may be the problem - your openssl may be not configured properly for this machine. What does "which openssl" says executed from the curl directory?

Comment: Ok so that outputed with `/usr/bin/openssl` So I ran the `ldd openssl` command in /usr/bin and I've pasted the output in the original post

Comment: @Oleg is that all good?